# Removing null or undefined from Angular observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am doing Angular state management using `BehaviourSubject`, but while pushing the data to store is adding `undefined` value to the end of the object (creating another `undefined` value). can any one suggest the way to remove?

```
{todos:[{"accountNo":"91957869","vpainfo":[{"vpa":"saasasa@fff"}]},undefined]}
```

The below are the sample snippets,

### behaviourStore.ts

```
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class Store<T> {
    state$: Observable<T>;
    private _state$: BehaviorSubject<T>;

    protected constructor (initialState: T) {
        this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
        this.state$ = this._state$.asObservable();
    }

    get state (): T {
        return this._state$.getValue();
    }

    setState (nextState: T): void {
        this._state$.next(nextState);
    }
}
```

### behaviourState.ts

```
export interface User {
    accountNo?: string;
    vpainfo: VPAinfo[]
  }
  export interface VPAinfo {
    vpa?: string;
  }
  export class BehaviourState {
    todos: User[]
  }
```

### behaviourReducer.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from './behaviourStore';
import { BehaviourState } from './behaviourState';
import * as fromActions from '../actions/users.actions';

@Injectable()
export class BehaviourReducer extends Store<BehaviourState> {
    constructor() {
        super(new BehaviourState());
    }
    callReducer(action: any) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case fromActions.ADD_TODO:
                this.setState({ ...this.state, todos: [action.payload.todo, ...this.state.todos] });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally adding the data in the below way,

```
const resultobj = {"accountNo":"91957869","vpainfo":[{"vpa":"saasasa@fff"]};
const action = { type: fromActions.ADD_TODO, payload: { todo: resultobj}};
this.behaviourReducer.callReducer(action);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not defined any default value for todos. It's showing undefined.

**Try this:**

```
export class BehaviourState {
    todos: User[] = [];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the initial value of the `todos` is `undefined`, so you need either assign an initial value to it within the `BehaviourState` class, like:

```js
export class BehaviourState {
  todos: User[] = [];
}
```

Or by handling null/undefined value within the `reducer` like the following:

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, todos: [action.payload.todo, (...this.state.todos || [])] });
```